# Isn't this Commentz-Walter algorithm buggy?

Tags: search-algorithms, strings

I've been trying to piece together an implementation of the Commentz-Walter string search algorithm. The idea is to construct a state machine from a trie, working backwards from the earliest feasible position.

The paper is available [here](https://gofile.io/d/BHMIw7), though it is a scanned printout from 40 years ago. I have also found a better quality pseudocode for the core search loop (image below). But it seems that neither description of the algorithm provides a way to 'back out' of a dead end: The current trie node `v` is only ever assigned to its own child. It seems that there is a missing step: once the inner loop has exhausted the possibility of a match, the current node should be changed.

An example of an input that fails my implementation tests is to find the string `bb` in `abb`: The search begins on the first `b`, finds that `ab` is invalid, and fails

Can anyone put me right?

---

Pseudocode of search algorithm:

[image: Commentz-Walter pseudocode]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you have to reset `v` to `root` at the same time as you reset `j` to `0` (in fact if you just add `depth` to your node, you can skip `j` and just use `v.depth`)